# navigation not working in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

i created an iPad application, in which navigation is not working,
for example on click of cell of tableView, it should navigate to new view.

code snippet for the same:

**appDelegate.m**

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];   
[window addSubview:navController.view];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

After this i am creating UIViewControllerSubclass, **crollnext**.

Inside this  file i am performing some operation,and finally in my **mainViewController**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    crollnext *crollController =[[crollnext alloc]initWithNibName:@"crollView" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:crollController animated:YES];
    [crollController changeProductText:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
}
```

Have i made any mistake in code ?

here is a screenshot

[image: screen]
 **Thanks In Advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[window addSubview:navController.view];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Notice that you are adding your viewController.view on top of the window's stack of views, after adding your navController.view. What you should do is something like this:

```
 UINavigationController navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

The navController, for itself its nothing. You need to fill it with something (in this case your viewController as the rootViewController.

Answer (score 2):

remove this line

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all what is the `viewController` object in your app delegate method. Also why is that you are adding the viewController's view to the `window`. You have added that as the root view for the `navigationController` which has been added to the `window`. So you dont need to add the view of the `viewController` to the `window`.

Comment: viewController is a object of my class

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont add the views from your view controllers as subviws to your window. Instead set the window's rootViewController property to your navigation controller.